# Incremental Group BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How I can achieve incremental grouping in query ?

[image]

I need to group by all the non-zero values into different named groups.

Please help me write a query based on columns date and subscribers.

Comment: Please explain your output.

Comment: Add table definition, sample data and your query

Comment: for 'group1', 'group2' ... understand the sequence, for 'no group' where it stand, at top of rows.

Comment: no group is the zero values.

Comment: Are you asking how to assign a count to contiguous blocks of non-zero values (in ascending date order)? (The `?` column is your desired output?) If that is the case, try searching for `gaps and islands`.

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. For example, Gordon's answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808583/numbering-islands-in-sql-server-2012) related question only applies to recent versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SQL Server 2012 or newer, you can use few tricks with windows functions to get this kind of grouping without cursors, with something like this:

```
select
  Date, Subscribers,
  case when Subscribers = 0 then 'No group'
  else 'Group' + convert(varchar, GRP) end as GRP
from (
  select
    Date, Subscribers,
    sum (GRP) over (order by Date asc) as GRP
  from (
    select
      *,
      case when Subscribers > 0 and 
        isnull(lag(Subscribers) over (order by Date asc),0) = 0 then 1 else 0 end as GRP
    from SubscribersCountByDay S
  ) X
) Y
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/858e7/1)

Answer (score 1):

In general I advocate AGAINST cursors but in this case it ill not hurt since it ill iterate, sum up and do the conditional all in one pass.
Also note I hinted it with `FAST_FORWARD` to not degrade performance.

I'm guessing you do want what @HABO commented.

See the working example below, it just sums up until find a ZERO, reset and starts again. Note the `and @Sum > 0` handles the case where the first row is ZERO.

```
create table dbo.SubscribersCountByDay
(
    [Date] date not null
   ,Subscribers int not null
)

GO

insert into dbo.SubscribersCountByDay
([Date], Subscribers)
values
 ('2015-10-01', 1)
,('2015-10-02', 2)
,('2015-10-03', 0)
,('2015-10-04', 4)
,('2015-10-05', 5)
,('2015-10-06', 0)
,('2015-10-07', 7)

GO

declare
 @Date date
,@Subscribers int
,@Sum int = 0
,@GroupId int = 1

declare @Result as Table
(
   GroupName varchar(10) not null
  ,[Sum] int not null
)

declare ScanIt cursor fast_forward
for
(
  select [Date], Subscribers
   from dbo.SubscribersCountByDay
   union
   select '2030-12-31', 0
)  order by [Date]
open ScanIt

fetch next from ScanIt into @Date, @Subscribers

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

    if (@Subscribers = 0 and @Sum > 0)
    begin
       insert into @Result (GroupName, [Sum]) values ('Group ' + cast(@GroupId as varchar(6)), @Sum)
       set @GroupId = @GroupId + 1
       set @Sum = 0
    end
    else begin
       set @Sum = @Sum + @Subscribers
    end

    fetch next from ScanIt into @Date, @Subscribers
end

close ScanIt
deallocate ScanIt


select * from @Result
GO
```

For the OP: Please next time write the table, just posting an image is lazy

Comment: You might want to look at the set-based answers. A cursor isn't really needed.

Comment: @HABO that solution was my first though but for the sake of performance I reallized it ill need to iterate at least twice in the raw data, one with a case to "build" the groups and another to aggregate. A cursor here wraps everything in one go. Also with a large set you ill need more memory. Remember cursors are not recomended because it cost (in cycles and memory) but in this case it ill performe better IMHO

Answer (score 1):

In a version of SQL Server modern enough to support CTEs you can use the following cursorless query:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @SampleData as Table ( Id Int Identity, Subscribers Int );
insert into @SampleData ( Subscribers ) values
  -- ( 0 ), -- Test edge case when we have a zero first row.
  ( 200 ), ( 100 ), ( 200 ),
  ( 0 ), ( 0 ), ( 0 ),
  ( 50 ), ( 50 ), ( 12 ),
  ( 0 ), ( 0 ),
  ( 43 ), ( 34 ), ( 34 );
select * from @SampleData;

-- Run the query.
with ZerosAndRows as (
  -- Add   IsZero   to indicate zero/non-zero and a row number to each row.
  select Id, Subscribers,
    case when Subscribers = 0 then 0 else 1 end as IsZero,
    Row_Number() over ( order by Id ) as RowNumber
    from @SampleData ),
  Groups as (
  -- Add a group number to every row.
  select Id, Subscribers, IsZero, RowNumber, 1 as GroupNumber
    from ZerosAndRows
    where RowNumber = 1
  union all
  select FAR.Id, FAR.Subscribers, FAR.IsZero, FAR.RowNumber,
    -- Increment   GroupNumber   only when we move from a non-zero row to a zero row.
    case when Groups.IsZero = 1 and FAR.IsZero = 0 then Groups.GroupNumber + 1 else Groups.GroupNumber end
    from ZerosAndRows as FAR inner join Groups on Groups.RowNumber + 1 = FAR.RowNumber
  )
-- Display the results.
select Id, Subscribers,
  case when IsZero = 0 then 'no group' else 'Group' + Cast( GroupNumber as VarChar(10) ) end as Grouped
  from Groups
  order by Id;
```

To see the intermediate results just replace the final `select` with `select * from FlagsAndRows` or `select * from Groups`.